# Pass the columns of each row in a result set to a stored function in single step

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

The following is my stored function

```
            DELIMITER $$;
            CREATE FUNCTION set_credit_values (emp_id bigint, lpc_id int, elc_date date) RETURNS date DETERMINISTIC
            BEGIN

                SELECT do_credit(emp_id, lpc_id, elc_date,ltp_id, lpb_cr_count, lpb_cr_on, lpb_next_cr,  lpb_cr_period) 
                FROM erp_leave_policy_body,erp_leave_type 
                WHERE lpb_fk_leave_policy = lpc_id AND ltp_id = lpb_fk_leave_type AND ltp_status=1;

                RETURN elc_date;
            END $$;
            DELIMITER ;
```

I need to pass the selected values in each row in the result set (by the SELECT query) to `do_credit()` function. But it is showing errors as

```
#1415 - Not allowed to return a result set from a function
```

The `do_credit()` function is as

```
            DELIMITER $$;
            CREATE FUNCTION do_credit (emp_id bigint, lpc_id int, new_elc_date date,ltp_id int, cr_count tinyint, cr_on tinyint, next_cr date, cr_period tinyint) 
            RETURNS boolean DETERMINISTIC
            BEGIN
                DECLARE next_credit_date DATE DEFAULT NULL; 
                DECLARE is_credited INT(11) DEFAULT 0;                    

                SET next_credit_date = get_next_credit(emp_id, lpc_id, new_elc_date,ltp_id, cr_on, next_cr, cr_period);

                IF next_credit_date = new_elc_date THEN

                    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO is_credited FROM erp_employee_leave_credits WHERE
                    elc_fk_employees = emp_id AND elc_fk_leave_policy = lpc_id AND elc_fk_leave_type = ltp_id AND elc_date = new_elc_date;
                    -- If the leave is not credited yet
                    IF is_credited = 0 THEN
                        INSERT INTO erp_employee_leave_credits(elc_fk_employees,elc_fk_leave_policy,elc_fk_leave_type,elc_date,elc_cr_count) VALUES (emp_id,lpc_id,ltp_id,new_elc_date,cr_count);
                    END IF;

                END IF;
                RETURN 1;

            END $$;
            DELIMITER ;
```

It is working successfully.
I know using cursor. But when using cursor I should traverse through each row in the result set. So may take more time. If I call the function with the select query it works faster than cursor. So How can solve this error.

Comment: Your second function seems to provide and answer - why not select into in your first function?